# Reliably counting the number of client connections to a SignalR hub

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm creating a web dashboard that will display the status of our test environments.

I use a hub to connect the browser to the server and have a background task that polls the status of the environment. I only want to perform this check if at least one client is connected.

My hub looks a little like this:

```
public class StatusHub : Hub
{
    private static int connectionCount = 0;

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref connectionCount);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref connectionCount);
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref connectionCount);
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    // other useful stuff
}
```

This mainly works but sometimes OnConnected is called but OnDisconnected is not.

One specific case is if I open chrome and type the address of the page but don't actually navigate to it. It seems Chrome is pre-fetching the page and connecting, but never disconnecting.

So two questions:

1. Is this a good approach to counting connections (I'm never going to be running in a web farm environment)?
2. Will these zombied connections from Chrome eventually timeout (I tried setting timeouts very low but still didn't get a disconnect)?

Answer (score 1):

The events will always fire. If they don't, file a bug with repro steps on github. To get a more accurate number, you can store a hashset of connection ids and get the count from that.